# What does file:///private/var/mobile/Containers/Shared/AppGroup and Electronic business cards mean?

Tags: sms, sharefile

I notice when I send my friend a phone wnumber from my contact list it came up as a electronic business card. She did t know what that meant either. When I copy paste it on the web it comes up as file:///private/var/mobile/Containers/Shared/File//AppGroup/972CBF64-53BF-4465-8C96-4F068BBECE9B/File%20Provider%20

I started to mess around with my other apps to see what I might say it always shows up as a private mobile shared file different type of stuff like that.
Is this normal for iPhone? A lot of things I do always comes up saying xcodes and swift. Also when I try to look all this up
It talks about sharing your data to a mac? I don’t have a mac but know someone who does that I’m not comfortable with. Is this all normal just for a iPhone??

phone freezes passwords being changed
Notifications conking up like I have a Mac and I watch. I have screenshots but I don’t see where to put them on here